# Special Product of two Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Please, for the two lists

```
L1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
L2 = {{{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{i, j}, {k, q}}}
```

The desired result is

```
{{{ae, bf}, {ag, bh}}, {{ci, dj}, {ck, dq}}}
```

Comment: One tangential comment, for a list with constant values, use `Set (=)` not `SetDelayed (:=)`.

Comment: Also, do you mean `{{{a e, b f}, {a g, b h}}, {{c i, d j}, {c k, d q}}}` (`b h` instead of `c h`)

Comment: Yes , i meant that

Answer (score 8):

```
L1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
L2 = {{{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{i, j}, {k, q}}}

Transpose[L1 Transpose[L2, {1, 3, 2}], {1, 3, 2}]
```

> {{{a e, b f}, {a g, b h}}, {{c i, d j}, {c k, d q}}}

Comment: Thanks, it is the most appropriate answer for general case

Answer (score 7):

One way would be

```
l1 = {{a,b},{c,d}};
l2 = {{{e,f},{g,h}},{{i,j},{k,q}}};

Partition[Riffle[l1,l1],2] l2
(* {{{a e, b f},{a g, b h}},{{c i, d j},{c k, d q}}} *)
```

The idea behind this solution is to expand `l1` into the same shape as `l2`

```
Partition[Riffle[l1,l1],2]
(* {{{a,b},{a,b}},{{c,d},{c,d}}} *)
```

and then use Mathematicas builtin elementwise multiplication on similar shaped lists to get the result.

Another possible solution:

```
MapTimes[x_,{y_,z_}] := {x y,x z}
MapTimes @@@ Transpose[{l1,l2}]
(* {{{a e, b f},{a g, b h}},{{c i, d j},{c k, d q}}} *)
```

Comment: It works, thanks for your recommendations

Comment: Glad it works for you!

Answer (score 7):

```
L1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
L2 = {{{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{i, j}, {k, q}}};

Transpose /@ (L1*(Transpose /@ L2))

(*  {{{a e, b f}, {a g, b h}}, {{c i, d j}, {c k, d q}}}  *)
```

or

```
Thread /@ (L1*(Thread /@ L2))

(*  {{{a e, b f}, {a g, b h}}, {{c i, d j}, {c k, d q}}}  *)

% == %%

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Flatten[ Flatten[L2, {{1}, {3}}] L1, {{1}, {3}}]
```

or

```
Function[x, # x] /@ #2 & @@@ Thread[{L1, L2}]
```

> {{{a e, b f}, {a g, b h}}, {{c i, d j}, {c k, d q}}}

Answer (score 2):

```
la = {{{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{i, j}, {k, q}}};

lb = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
```

Combining `MapThread` and `Threaded` (new in 13.1)

```
MapThread[#1 * Threaded[#2] &, {la, lb}]
```

{{{a e, b f}, {a g, b h}}, {{c i, d j}, {c k, d q}}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `Thread` and `Dot`:

```
L1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
L2 = {{{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{i, j}, {k, q}}};

List @@@ # &@*Dot @@@ (Reverse /@ Thread[{L1, L2}])

(*{{{a e, b f}, {a g, b h}}, {{c i, d j}, {c k, d q}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

And another option is to use [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) with [`Diagonal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Diagonal.html)

```
Diagonal /@ Outer[Times, L2[[1]], L1[[1]]]
Diagonal /@ Outer[Times, L2[[2]], L1[[2]]]
Join[{%%, %}]
```

Which can be written as a one-liner

```
Table[Diagonal /@ Outer[Times, L2[[index]], L1[[index]]], {index, 1, 
  Length@L1}]
```

The result is:

> `{{{a e, b f}, {a g, b h}}, {{c i, d j}, {c k, d q}}}`